# awk to filter lines in file by removing pattern

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to remove the `IonCode_4 digits` (always 4 may be different) and leave the file extension. Is the below the best way? Thank you :).

**file**

```
1112233  ID_1234_000000-Control_z_zzzz_zz_zz_zz_zz_zz_zzz_zz-zzzz-zzz-zzz_zzzz_zzzz_zzz_zzz_zzz_zzz_zzz.txt
1112231  ID_1234_000000-Control_z_zzzz_zz_zz_zz_zz_zz_zzz_zz-zzzz-zzz-zzz_zzzz_zzzz_zzz_zzz_zzz_zzz_zzz.txt
```

**awk**

```
awk '/_tn_/ {next} gsub ("^.*/|_.*$|IonCode_...._", "", $2)'f
```

**current**

```
1112233  000000-Control
1112231  000000-Control
```

**desired**

```
1112233  000000-Control.txt
1112231  000000-Control.txt
```

Comment: The script you posted doesn't make any sense wrt your posted sample input. `/_tn_/ {next}` would do nothing and it's not even clear what you were hoping `"^.*/|_.*$|IonCode_...._"` would match. So no, I'd have to say that's not the best way. Is `IonCode` in your description and code actually `ID` in your example? If so is it always that or could it be something other than `ID`?

Comment: My apologies it is always `ID_4digits` (digits will be different each time). The `tn` is in some lines not all, so I included it just in case. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. This is simplest I could think, though we could do it with number of fields mentioning too but that will be more like hard-coding of numbers, so I went with this approach here.

```
awk '
{ 
  sub(/[^_]*_/,"",$2) 
  sub(/[^_]*_/,"",$2)
  sub(/_.*/,".txt")
}
1
' Input_file
```

Comment: The `.txt` is missing in the output, it looks the same as current. Thank you :).

Comment: @justaguy, thank you for letting know it is mid night here and I am writing code on mobile :)  Anyways I fixed it now lemme know how it goes now?

Answer (score 2):

Split records by 1+ spaces or underscore, so the 4th field will be the part you're interested in.

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]+|_' '!/_tn_/{print $1,$4".txt"}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/ID_[0-9]{4}_([^_]+).*(\..*)/\1\2/' file

1112233  000000-Control.txt
1112231  000000-Control.txt
```